# What’s the relation between definability of a class of structure and the completeness of a set of axioms?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Please help me with confusions of following terms: 1.Incompleteness 2.undefinable 3.non-standard model

If a structure has non-standard counterpart under a certain set of axioms, does that mean such structure is not definable in a certain language? (N,<) in first order logic would be an example. Does this also mean the axiom of (N,<) is not complete? Since we could create a sentence discribing something not in N,< but also prove it’s in N,<

Also, why non-standard model don’t exist in second order logic? An example would be R,

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by a _structure_ having a _model_? Usually it's theories, not structures, that have models.

Comment: It is not good practice to post the same question both here and in math.overflow, as [you have done](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313200/what-s-the-relation-between-definability-of-a-class-of-structure-and-imcomplenes). Pick one site and post it there. It seldom makes sense to post it in both, and you should only do so after it has gone long unanswered in one site (usually here). In which case, you should specify in the new post in overflow that the question has been asked here already (and link to it). You are violating norms of both sites right now.

Answer (score 1):

Any first order theory that has infinite models has many different models, due to the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem. This does not necessarily imply incompleteness. For instance, the theory of all first order sentences satisfied by the structure $(\mathbb Z, \le)$ is complete, but it has many models (they just all have the same first order properties). In fact the models are exactly $(L\times \mathbb Z, \preceq),$ where $L$ is any linearly ordered set and $\preceq$ is the dictionary order. But, for any incomplete theory $T$, if we let $\phi$ be some sentence that is neither provable nor refutable from the theory, the completeness theorem says there are models of $T+\{\phi\}$ and also models of $T+\{\lnot \phi\}.$

I would not say that the structure is not definable cause that term is used in a different way. However, it does mean that no set of first order sentences determine the structure up to isomorphism.

A second order theory is not necessarily categorical (i.e. does not necessarily have a unique model). However, due to the additional expressivity of second order semantics, much more control is available over the models: there is no Lowenheim-Skolem theorem in second order logic. For instance, we cannot express the fact that a structure is countable (or uncountable) in first order logic, but we can in second order.

You are probably under the impression that a second order theory has to be categorical because second order arithmetic famously is. The reason is cause you can write a sentence saying "the domain is $\mathbb N$" in the second order language (more precisely: "every element of the domain is in any set that contains zero and is closed under successor") and then can prove that sentence holds by induction (which is trivial if a bit disorienting).

(Note also these categoricity results require that we are only considering *full* models of second order logic, where the predicate variables actually must range over all predicates for the domain. Considering the more general class of models for second order logic (Henkin models) makes the semantics effectively first order.)

I’ve avoided the term “non-standard model” because the term is predicated on there being an “intended model”, which is not always the case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind answer. I am still a bit confused about the relation between “completeness” and “have one model up to isomorphism”for a set of axioms. From this link, it seems that he says first order PA is incomplete since it has multiple models. Please refer to the first 3 lines of his answer below. https://mathoverflow.net/a/14500/126554   Thank you so much.

Comment: @ZhaoYuqing Incompleteness implies having more than one model. Having more than one model does not imply incompleteness. This is consistent with what is said in the answer you linked.

Comment: @ZhaoYuqing If you like, incompleteness is stronger, since it implies having more than one model up to elementary equivalence, not just up to isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I say that 2nd order arithmetic is categorical if “predicate variables actually must range over all predicates for the domain”?(quoting you) because we have exhausted the domain? For completeness, can I say 2nd order arithmetic is complete due to the same reason(we have exhausted the domain)?

Comment: @ZhaoYuqing No I don't know what is meant by 'we have exhausted the domain'. This distinction between full and Henkin semantics is important but somewhat technical (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Semantics ). In any event, like I say in my answer, not all second order theories are categorical with respect to full semantics. I explain why 2nd order arithmetic is: "you can write a sentence saying..." It is (semantically) complete, since, as JDH says, categoricity implies semantic completeness. (Which is the contrapositive of "incompleteness implies more than one model.")

Comment: @ZhaoYuqing A few more words on arithmetic: We know that even in first order axiomatizations that we can demand any model has a least element $0,$ and be closed under a successor function. This immediately implies that any model has an initial segment that behaves like $\mathbb N.$ What can't be ruled out in first order logic is there being other segments that look like $\mathbb Z$ above that. What we need to do to have categoricity is find a way to say "there's only that initial segment, that's it," and this is only possible in second order logic.